# How do I remove the laminate/sun mica from my old computer table without damaging the plyboard underneath?

Tags: woodworking, carpentry, plywood, hardware, laminate

I have an old computer table, made of plywood panels with wooden sections here and there. It has been in the family for some time now, and I don't wish to discard it. I wish to remove the laminate / sun mica that it came with, and finish off the panels by staining them, and upgrading the hardware such as drawer knobs, locks, sliders and castors.

My pain is that the laminate wont come off without a fight. As is with everything old school (from like 10 12 years ago), the laminate is glued on there nice, and even ironing over it doesn't seem to help without damaging the ply underneath.

Any help to be able to remove the ply, and tips for refinishing the substrate would be appreciated. I had originally panned to stain it in some dark colour, but your ideas are most appreciated.

Comment: Removal of the laminate, especially with the glue residue, in order to get to a layer that can be stained, is going to be tough. Laminate is plastic. I've never tried to pry it up but maybe it can be done, then belt sand off the contact cement residue. Have you considered gluing a wood veneer over the laminate and finishing that?

Comment: They usually don't use the nice plywoods that would look good stained for laminated desks/tables.  Might not be as happy doing all that work instead of adding nice staining wood on top.

Answer (score 1):

Laminates will, eventually, start peeling on their own. When that happens, you discover that there's a mess of contact cement left behind that needs to be scraped off before you can reattach the laminate.

Since you want to remove what sounds like well attached laminate, you'll have to start by prying up an edge somewhere. You'll need something like a short, sturdy paint scraper in order to wedge the edge of it under an edge of the laminate, most likely at a corner where 2 pieces meet. Once you have a small corner of your scraper in there, you'll need to continue to pry and scrape and pry and scrape to remove the laminate. Be prepared for a workout - the contact cement, factory applied with heat and pressure, won't be eager to let go.

It's likely that, as you get some of the sheet lifted, it'll crack. This will leave you with a removed piece in your hand and some still attached to the desk. You'll have the joy of wedging your scraper in there again to make another starting spot, except that it's likely to be more difficult, because instead of a vertical edge, you'll likely have a sloped edge - attached to the wood and sloping away toward the surface of the laminate. This will make it even more difficult to get something wedged between the laminate and wood.

Once you get all the laminate off, since you're looking to produce some sort of bare wood finish on this desk, you're going to be spending a lot of time scraping and sanding to get all the adhesive off. A *lot* of time. Fortunately contact cement doesn't really soak into the wood, so it should just be on the surface. However, as you'll have discovered when trying to remove the laminate, it doesn't like to let go. It won't want to let go of the wood substrate any more than it did the laminate.

Once you've *finally* managed to get all the laminate and all the glue off of it. You're likely going to be very disappointed in what you have left. If this piece is only 10-12 years old, it's very likely that it was made out of particle board (press board/chip board) something that's made by taking wood dust, mixing it with glue, then pressing it under heat and high pressure into a board shape. This isn't going to be pretty wood and it won't take stain well at all.

You'd be able to paint it, but then, if you're going to paint it, just scuff up the laminate (something like a ScotchBright™ pad, or steel wool), and directly paint it, and save all the sweating.

If it *is* actually plywood, there's a non-zero chance that the surface ply will actually be torn off as you're pulling the laminate off, giving you a damaged surface to try to repair prior to refinishing.

Comment: In my old job in a cabinet shop, we would use lacquer thinner to remove contact-glued plastic laminate.  Put the thinner in a squeeze bottle with a very thin hole. Get the laminate started with a scraper and pour the thinner into the contact cement between the laminate and the substrate. Peel slowly, keeping the line where the laminate touches the substrate wet with lacquer. If the contact cement is not decades old, the laminate will slowly peel off. Proper ventilation and surface protection is needed. Then use the thinner to scrape clean the left-over cement on the substrate.

Comment: Nice tip, @Triplefault. Still not a pretty surface to stain if the laminate was over particle board...